Using sp_add_target_group to add a target group fails with a constraint error about a database name
I have a pair of Elastic Job agents running on separate Azure SQL Servers.
On server A, I can create a new target group in SQL:
sp_add_target_group @target_group_name = 'mygroup'

On server B, I cannot create any new target groups in SQL. They all fail with a table level check constraint error:

The INSERT statement conflicted with the CHECK constraint "CK_sql_database_target_database_name_not_null". The conflict occurred in database "sthft-Jobs", table "jobs_internal.targets".

Adding the same group with the Elastic Job agent in the Azure Portal just works (ie, using the same name, the UI creates the group & I can read the data from the table, just like I expected the stored procedure to add it).
Why does Server B fail with the table constraint but server A does not?
Underpinning sp_add_target_group is a simple, direct insert into what turns out to be a view:
[jobs_internal].targets

This is a simple filter on jobs_internal.targets.
The stored procedure does a uniqueness check, then creates a new guid & sets the target type to be TargetGroup before attempting the insert.
The check constraint is defined as:
[target_type]<>'SqlDatabase' OR [database_name] IS NOT NULL

It is the same constraint definition as per the table in the database on Server A, which works just fine.
Since the target type is hard-coded into the stored procedure, the new row will always pass the check.
This suggests that the insert is tripping the constraint check, which is then failing some row of data already in the table.
I can't find a row in the table that defies the check either though.
Every row with targettype='SqlDatabase' has a non-null value in database_name
Every row with targettype<>'SqlDatabase' has database_name of NULL
There are no rows where targettype IS NULL
I have rebuilt all the indexes on the table, in case it was that.
Annoyingly, the Azure UI appears happy to create whatever target groups it wants in the db.
I'm sure there is a very simple explanation for my error, since I expect the Azure UI is using the same underlying stored procedure that I am successfully using on server A & unsuccessfully calling on server B. So what have I missed here?
(there is no connection between the 2x servers & there is no multi-server targeting that could confuse this)

I don't have azure in front of me but guessing the gui does different things before calling the above procedure, or it uses different user acc with other set of rights. Can you trace the calls it makes by running extended events or whatever it's called in azure?


The INSERT statement conflicted with the CHECK constraint "CK_sql_database_target_database_name_not_null". The conflict occurred in database "sthft-Jobs", table "jobs_internal.targets".

As you said that the Azure Portal can establish the target group without any problems it suggests that the databases and underlying permissions are probably configured appropriately.

Make sure the Elastic Job agent on Server B has the appropriate rights to enter data into the jobs_internal.targets table1 using the SQL Server login that it is using. Permissions can occasionally be disregarded while configuring many servers.

Check to see if Server B's database and Server A have the same compatibility level. sometimes differences in compatibility levels might result in unexpected behavior when using checks.


SELECT compatibility_level FROM sys.databases WHERE  name = 'dbname';


Verify whether Server A and Server B's versions of SQL Server vary in any way.


Could be. I see level 16 on the one that works & level 15 on the one that doesn't.
Permissions are solid: both dbs were created from the Azure UI & inherit the server owner as their dbo, which in this case is also being used to setup the jobs.
I will get back when I have been able to validate further - the downlevel db is a significant production db, so I will need to see if I can recreate the issue elsewhere & get a CR to raise the level here.
